# Upgrade Lambda Python 2.7 to 3.9 - Library Dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lxml, cx-oracle

We have a AWS Lambda Python 2.7 function with multiple libraries (lxml, lib & cx_Oracle-7.0.0.dist-info). We want to upgrade the Python 2.7 code to 3.9 and we are pretty clear on how to do that but we are not sure how to handle the library dependencies to get those upgraded or if they even need to be upgraded. Any help would be appreciated as we are a bit new to this.

Comment: Do you package them with the Python code itself? Or are they layers? What's the process you use? Do you use `pip`?

Comment: Don't forget to look at upgrading cx_Oracle to the new major version, now called python-oracledb.  see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  You may be able to avoid installing Oracle Instant Client.  But if the cryptography package gives you grief, see https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-python-oracledb-without-the-cryptography-package.  Also see https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-python-oracle-connection